# two column form with dynamic number of rows in each column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to design the following form where there will be 2 column. Each column can have any number of form field like left column can have only one form field and right column can have also one form field only or left column can have two form field and right column can have three form field and vice versa.

The way i am doing does not separates two columns. Here is what i have done

Here is what i tried using flex

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.input-wrapper {
  flex: 1;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="input-wrapper">
    <label>Additional Space</label>
    <select>
      <option>hello</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="input-wrapper">
    <label>Size</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="length" />
  </div>
  <div class="input-wrapper">
    <label></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="width" />
  </div>
  <div class="input-wrapper">
    <label></label>
    <select>
      <option>hello</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>


<div class="row">
  <div class="input-wrapper">
    <label>Additional Space</label>
    <select>
      <option>hello</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="input-wrapper">
    <label>Size</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="length" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the design

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to set `width: 100%` to the input type you want to span. In your layout, the container already takes the full width.

You should also use `display:flex` on your `input-wrapper` and set

```
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: flex-end;
```

In order for the text to be shown first and the inputs on the second line.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.input-wrapper {
  flex: 1;
  padding-left: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}


select{
  width: 100%;
}

select, input{
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  padding: 6px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

label{
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #d1d1d1;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="input-wrapper">
    <label>Additional Space</label>
    <select>
      <option>hello</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="input-wrapper">
    <label>Size</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="length" />
  </div>
  <div class="input-wrapper">
    <label></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="width" />
  </div>
  <div class="input-wrapper">
    <label></label>
    <select>
      <option>hello</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>


<div class="row">
  <div class="input-wrapper">
    <label>Additional Space</label>
    <select>
      <option>hello</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="input-wrapper">
    <label>Size</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="length" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution but i think there is a problem. It does not look like 2 column. I copied your code and tried to mimic the UI as in screenshot for better picture of what i am wanting it seems it is not exact.https://jsbin.com/guwotuyahe/1/edit?css,output . Level and Room field should take the space as of Number of Bedrooms and Size fields should take the space of Including Basement Bedrooms.

Comment: There are no Bedrooms and Basement in your example, so it's hard to understand what you are trying to achieve

Comment: there is in the attached image Number of Bedrooms and Including Basement Bedrooms